# ffmpeg HE-AAC 'unsupported codec' despite being compiled with support

Tags: ffmpeg, aac

Lack of default support of AAC for ffmpeg is really annoying:

My ffmpeg version:

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-05-02-0d81edc Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/HEAD-0d81edc_1 --enable-shared --cc=clang --host-cflags=-fno-stack-check --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-htmlpages --enable-libbluray --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librsvg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libtwolame --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb
```

I have several segment.ts files in `edit.txt` and I try to concatenate and convert to mpg:
`ffmpeg -f concat -i edit.txt -c copy   output.mpg`

this does not work

```
Input #0, concat, from 'edit.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 121 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 30 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (HE-AAC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 121 kb/s
File 'output.mpg' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpeg @ 0x7f8e44807e00] VBV buffer size not set, using default size of 230KB
If you want the mpeg file to be compliant to some specification
Like DVD, VCD or others, make sure you set the correct buffer size
[mpeg @ 0x7f8e44807e00] Unsupported audio codec. Must be one of mp1, mp2, mp3, 16-bit pcm_dvd, pcm_s16be, ac3 or dts.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --
Conversion failed!
```

so I tried with `ffmpeg -f concat -i edit.txt -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac  output.mpg` -> same effect.

Why fraunhoffer codec exists and is mentioned on FFMPEG site if it is not supported?
Is it any way to do this?

Comment: what not use `-c:a copy` ?

Comment: Because with `-c:a copy` I got also error of unsupported codec

Answer (score 6):

This is an issue with the chosen output container format. Looks like `ffmpeg` doesn't want to put *aac* (codec) into an *mpeg program stream* (container). Try `.ts`, `.mp4`, or `.mkv` instead of `.mpg`.

Comment: Looks you may be right, but why ffmpeg behaves like this. I was able to make it work by `ffmpeg -f concat -i edit.txt -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts output.mpg` I need "mpg" extension because ChannelsDVR expect that. I am not sure what format I'm getting in result - mpeg2, mp4, mpg in ts container? looks pure mpg does not want having aac and only allows ac3